# Monitoring akka cluster health through http

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have an akka cluster deployment. I print out cluster health info in the logs but I was wondering if there is a way to monitor health of akka cluster through a rest endpoint out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to this module: https://github.com/akka/akka-management

Comment: thanks..what's the real difference between typesafe vs lightbend jars? I get tons of nosuchmethod errors

Comment: There is none, typesafe is the former name of the company behind all these libraries. Lightbend is the current name.